# Mysql query that includes TWO sums from columns in other tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

Got a query running one sum from a different table, which works perfectly (and obtained from this forum as well):

```
SELECT
    R.REP_ID as repid, R.REP_DESBREV as repdesc, 
    IFNULL(SUM(RD.REPDATA_CANT), 0) as cant
FROM 
    REPUESTOS R 
LEFT JOIN 
    REP_DATA RD, ON RD.REPDATA_REPID = R.REP_ID 
GROUP BY 
    RD.REPDATA_REPID
```

Now, the thing is that I'd like to add an extra column that obtains the total inventory (something like

```
IFNULL(SUM(I.INV_CANT), 0) as inv) 
FROM table INVENTARIO I
WHERE I.INV_REPID = R.REP_ID
```

This value can be obtained by means of a JOIN, in the exact same way we got the first statement that works, but I have not found the way to include BOTH SUMS in just one query.

Any ideas? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query example

```
select 
t1.id,
ifnull(sum(t1.my_column),0) as Sum1,
ifnull(other.sum,0) as Sum2
from table as t1
left join (select id , sum(other_table_column) from other_table group by id) as other
on t1.id = other.id
group by t1.id
```

Comment: Raheel, thanks for the quick answer. In your example, one of your sums belongs to the same t1 table, in my requirement both sums belong to two different tables, so the query includes a total of three tables...

Comment: @user1494526 there are the sum for 2 different tables, t1.my_column and other.sum

Comment: thisis only example in the join use another table and in the select call it

Comment: Thanks rasheel and jcho360 for your comments, thing is, I'm new to all this mysql stuff, and have been trying to add the third table sum column with no satisfactory results. Will keep trying until I hit it. Thanks!

Comment: you can write another left join right after the first left join before group by and get sum as i have done in my query

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented the following statement:

```
SELECT
    R.REP_PARNUM as parnum,
    R.REP_ID as repid,
    R.REP_DESBREV as repdesc,
    IFNULL(SUM(RD.REPDATA_CANT),0) as cant,
    IFNULL(SUM(I.INV_CANT),0) as intt
FROM REPUESTOS R
LEFT JOIN REP_DATA RD ON RD.REPDATA_REPID = R.REP_ID
LEFT JOIN INVENTARIO I ON I.INV_REPID = R.REP_ID
GROUP BY R.REP_PARNUM
```

It actually runs, but the problem is that it's giving me some weird values. For example, some of the values in the first sum column (`REPDATA_CANT`) are shown with -3, i.e. if the real result is 20, it shows 17 and so on. In the second sum column (`INV_CANT`), it actually MULTIPLIES (in some rows, not all) the value by 3. Very weird behaviour, do you have an idea why?